# Using a number system other than the decimal

Tags: quadratics

Travelling in the Kingdom of Crystal Skull, Indiana Jones discovered a small box with notation 
$$
3 x^2 - 25 x + 66 = 0 \implies  x_1 = 4,\; x_2 = 9,
$$
which seems to be incorrect. However after some reflection he realised a number system other than the decimal was used to determine the roots of the quadratic equation. What is the base of that number system?

Comment: I can find nothing on google, but the phrasing of this problem screams "contest problem"...

Answer (score 0):

If the base is $b>9$ (assuming the digits from $0$ to $9$ have the same meaning as in our standard decimal system), we have
$$
3\cdot 4^2-(2b+5)\cdot 4+6b+6=0
$$